# Laravel double where returning no result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to do a double where on my table, but even if the arguments are correct I cannot view any result:
Here is my Review model:

```
class Reviews extends Model
{
 protected $fillable=['id','product_id', 'user_id', 'rating', 'comment', 
'approved', 'spam'];

 public function user()
  {
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

 public function product()
   {
 return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
```

And this is my controller, where I pass the values and make the query;
a DD on the values shows them correctly:

```
  public function storereview(Request $request){

  $uid=Auth::user()->id;
  $productID = $request->id;
  $matchThese = ['product_id' => $productID, 'user_id' => $uid];
  $result=Reviews::where($matchThese);

          dd($result);
```

The DD of result shows this: 
https://ibb.co/fSzRGH

I made a screenshot cause I can't indent this here.

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `get()` to actually execute the query:

```
$result = Reviews::where($matchThese)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [get()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#retrieving-results) to get the result.

```
Reviews::where($matchThese)->get();
```